# Docker and Angular build cannot find file

Tags: angular, docker, build

I am preparing to release an angular application within Docker. My Docker file looks as follows

```
#step 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g npm@9.2.0
run npm run build --prod

#step 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/taims /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I  run npm run build --prod outside of the Docker file I don't receive this error. What am I missing?
At the very end of the build, I receive the following error

```
Error: src/app/modules/internal/signals/signals.component.ts:11:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../models/fundamentals/GeneralInfo' or its corresponding type declarations.
#13 51.57
#13 51.57 11 import { GeneralInfo } from '../../../models/fundamentals/GeneralInfo';
```

When I run

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?  It doesn't look like you `npm install` or `npm ci` your application's dependencies; is this possibly related to your problem?

Comment: I don't have a .dockerignore file. I did try the npm install and npm ci in the dockerfile but that kicked out the same error.

Comment: There's a range of potential errors that can result from using the host's `node_modules` directory in the container environment.  One thing to try is to add `node_modules` to a `.dockerignore` file, then `RUN npm ci` after you `COPY package.json package-lock.json ./`.  If you run the container with a volume mount that hides the image's code, also try removing this.  Does this approach make a difference?